# TimeGraph with history from "lastlog" data

Tags: grafana

I would like to display data in the TimeSeries panel, which is pulled from a "lastlog" type table in the DB (in my case it's MySQL), letting the Grafana keep history of the data.

In short - is there any way to make Grafana "add" a timestamp to the data everytime it is pulled?

Longer version:
I have data that looks like this:

| UserID | IsOnline |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | True |
| 02 | False |

and so on,

I have a simple select statement to pull the number of online users (and total number of users for that matter) like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalUsers,
SUM(case when us.UserStatus=TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OnlineUsers
FROM UserStatus us
```

This table just keeps the info about all the user statuses, but I don't have any "userlog" table that tracks the total number of users that are online that is timebased, which causes abovementioned question - is there any way to let Grafana "timestamp" each executed query, so that it is presentable in a time-series?
In this case I keep getting error that there is no timestamp in the query (quite obviously :)). I've sort-of managed to work around this by adding SYSDATE() to the select statement, but that then only displays the actual value (which also makes sense as the query returns only one row - with current timestamp)

I debated two solutions:

- to create a log table in DB for the online users and use procedures to log the values
- To create an app to pull the logs and store them in a time series DB for easy integration with Grafana (I guess Prometheus would be the first choice for Grafana)

Option 1 seems to be very performance heavy, as I would either need to create a log everytime this value changes or have something running in the background (like an timed event) to do that for me (which is basically option 2 but without the hustle of another DB)
Option 2 (and option 1 too, now that I think about it) are not that scalable, as for every new thing I would like to monitor I would need to create/update tables/procedures.

My hope would be to have something like a TimeSeries in Grafana that is able to keep it's own history (almost like adding a sensor in homeassistant). I am aware this has it's own drawbacks, but I am still willing to go for it, if it is possible.

Appreciate all the feedback.

PS. I am new to Grafana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Grafana can not do what you want: Grafana designed for visualisation, not storing timeseries.

---

I believe options you described are you only options.

A bit more ideas on those options.

1. You can use job to insert updated data into timeseries table every n seconds. This will be similar to Prometheus' approach.
2. There are a couple sql exporters, that allow Prometheus to scrape results of arbitrary query, so no need to create your own app. But if this is only use of Prometheus you envision, thisisprobably over kill, and creating a job and one timeseries table would be more efficient.